# When using a VPA (Variable-Pitch Connector) to connect roof rafters to a top plate, how and where do you install hurricane ties?

Tags: framing, structural, hardware, lumber, building-regulations

When a VPA to attach rafters to a top plate, it seems there isn't room left for your normal hurricane tie to be put in place:

[image]

The part of the VPA that nails on to the top plate obstructs the ability to put a hurricane tie in, at least the ties that I've seen:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

So how do you install a hurricane tie? I can't find any information saying that a tie is not needed with a VPA, and I even had an informal conversation with a structural engineer saying that the tie is still needed with the VPA, but she didn't explain *how* to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends. VPA’s have an uplift value and unless you live in an extreme high wind area, you probably don’t need an additional holddown.

As you can see from Simpson’s product load table, VPA’s have an uplift value of 255 lbs. for Douglas Fir / Southern Pine and 220 lbs. for Spruce and Hem-Fir. See here: https://www.strongtie.com/raftertowallconnectors_solidsawnlumberconnectors/vpa_connect/p/vpa

Likewise, a standard hurricane tie like H1 allows 480 for DF/SP and 420 for SPF, as seen here.

https://www.strongtie.com/hurricanetiesforplatedtruss_trusstiedowns/h-tsp_productgroup_wcc/p/h.tsp

If higher uplift loads are required, I’d use a “twist strap” with VPA’s.

Answer (score 0):

Please note, that the hurricane clips are used on rafters that have horizontal notches (birds' mouth) that allow the rafter to set flat to the top plate. The variable pitch clip, does not need the notch. Depending on the way you cut the rafters, or not, determines which clip you use. One replaces the other, depending on the cut.

Comment: Are you saying that a hurricane tie is not needed when a VPA is used?

Comment: As @Lee Sam says, depends on what the code requires for uplift resistance. That info changes from area to area